# How to save a pipe operation result on environment variable without using an auxiliary file?

Tags: shell, pipe

I would like to save a pipe result operation directly on a variable, how to do that on linux shell script?

Example:

1. Input file:

> 20140512 34
>
> 20140512 51
>
> 20140512 25
>
> 20140512 84
>
> 20140512 09
>
> 20140512 29

2. First value of variable:

> test_var="Result"

3. Operation to execute:

> cat testeFile.txt | awk '{FS=","} {print $2}'

4. Expected result on variable:

> Result 34
>
> 51
>
> 25
>
> 84
>
> 09
>
> 29

**Note:**

*The idea is to save directly the 3rd point operation result on variable and not get only de 4th result.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, you can put scripts inside of `$()` to run them and insert the result in place of the `$()`:

```
test_var="Result $(awk '{FS=","} {print $2}' testeFile.txt)"
```

If you want to append to an existing variable, use this:

```
test_var="Result"
test_var="${test_var} $(awk '{FS=","} {print $2}' testeFile.txt)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer @Aaron Dingulla, i'm testing now.

Comment: This will work for any POSIX-compliant shell, not just `bash`.

Comment: @Aaron, this will show the result as my example describes, but the main point is to append/prepend directily on variable. Imagine that we have another operation and we want to append on `test_var`.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, after testing, it's not working like i expected. I'm executing this: tmp_filex="{$tmp_filex} $(ls -l PSC-SDPInapHD_1.0_SDP*'echo $line'* | awk '{FS=" "} {print $9}')"

Comment: What's the `*'echo $line'*` doing there in the middle of the script?

Comment: I can't edit, it was my mistake. Forget about that. Can you help me on this?

Comment: It's `${`, not `{$` ... If you have other problems, always include the exact error message that you get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62583/discussion-between-cold-and-aaron-digulla).